# OBIEE 12C Report distribution

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, obiee

My team is currently facing an issue distributing a mass of reports from OBIEE. I was just wondering what tools any oracle developers have used to distribute OBIEE reports to a LOT of users at once. Also, the users are not permissioned to OBIEE. Therefore, the reports have to be exported then distributed.

I'm very new to Oracle (about two months experience) so any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an agent to distribute this report by email?

More information about how to create an agent:
[How to create an OBIEE Agent](https://www.learn-it-with-examples.com/datawarehouse-bigdata/bi/oracle-bi-analytics/create-agent-obiee-analytics.html)

Comment: The issue with that is we have thousands of recipients to send these reports to (with different parameters for each). I was wondering if anyone has been using any programmatic way of distributing OBIEE reports. Thank you

Comment: The default configuration applies a 65,000 row limit to agents. Which may not be suitable for @Joe scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically it depends on what content it is you are distributing.

## Analysis

If it is individual analyses you are distributing you can use the `AnalysisExportViews` service (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIEIT/toc.htm)
and distribute the output as required.

## Publisher

If it is Publisher content there is a different set of web services (there are RESTful and SOAP APIs)
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/bip/BIPAP/index.html and
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/bip/BIPDV/index.html

## Dashboard

Things get more complicated here as there isn't an API to produce this.
The closest you can get is to use a GO URL (https://datacadamia.com/dat/obiee/obips/go_url) which essentially replicates a user access via a browser so you need to simulate logging in, store cookies etc.    This is limited to replicating the option to print to PDF and export to Excel.

## Implementation

Each option should programmatically give you a file you can then distribute as you want.   You will however need some way of storing the metadata to define what parameters apply to which users and pass these across to the relevant API / URL

Comment: I faced the same question as OP and tried using AnalysisExportViews.
However in the AnalysisExportResult structure that is returned both queryID and completeAnalysisExport are blank. Without the query ID I can't use the completeAnalysisExport method. Does this mean the complete data is returned in viewData?

Comment: @Manuel yes I believe if you have set `async` in `AnalysisExportExecutionOptions` to false you won't get a `query ID` or `completeAnalysisExport` as they are only needed when you are doing things asynchronously.   Just access `viewData` in the results which should be the actual report.